# How to parse large files using flatpack

Tags: java, flatpack

I need to parse files that may be quite large, possibly 100s of megabytes and millions of lines. I have been trying to do this using [FlatPack](http://flatpack.sourceforge.net/). I would think the way to do this would be to use the buffered parsers and the new stream methods. But, despite that dataset.next() returns true for the correct number of records, the Optional returned by dataset.getRecord() never contains a value.

I have looked at this [example/test](https://github.com/Appendium/flatpack/blob/master/flatpack-samples/src/main/java/net/sf/flatpack/examples/largedataset/largecsvperformancetest/CSVLarge.java)  but it only counts the number of record and does not actually do anything with the content.
example/test

Answer (score 0):

You can use the class BuffReaderParseFactory instead of DefaultParserFactory.

It will read one record from the input file only when you call "next()".

Comment: I believe the example I linked to uses the Buffered classes but it does not do anything meaningful with the content.

I need to have access to the field content of the record but when I try to access it I am getting errors.

Answer (score 0):

The explanations for both DefaultParserFactory and BuffReaderParseFactory are not exactly helpful. Both libraries said to return `PZParser` (from `newDelimitedParser`) but only one of them returns an actual value from a record. Based on the examples I've seen, I think `BuffReaderParseFactory` is just for checking performance (hence should be faster) and `DefaultParserFactory` on the other hand contains all the records.